# How can I boot my dual-booted Mac back to OS X?

Tags: macos, windows, startup, dual-boot

I have a MacBook Pro and run Windows XP on it too much however I cannot remember how I can open the MacBook Pro with OS X on instead of Windows XP. How can I boot back to OS X?

Answer (score 3):

**Hold ⌥ on boot and select your OS X partition.** This changes your boot partition once for that time you boot.

If you want to change it permanently, boot to OS X, open System Preferences → Startup Disk and select your OS X partition, or boot to Windows, open the Boot Camp Control Panel and select the OS X partition as the boot partition. Then, you will need to ⌥-boot to boot to Windows.

Comment: I also believe there is a control panel in Windows that let you choose the startup disk.

Comment: @Édouard Indeed — forgot about that

Comment: That control panel can be uninstalled though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Hold option key upon start up, two HDD will apperas, select the bootcamp disk or windows disk and you are done.